# How to recursively crawl links JSOUP?

Tags: java, mysql, jsoup

I am crawling a url and adding the url links on that page to a mysql table. Is there anyway I can further crawl each link that I found and list the links within that page, and then further crawl all those links etc...

Here is my crawl function:

```
    String url = "http://jsoup.org";

    try
    {
        Statement stat = connection.createStatement();
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");

        for (Element link : links) {
            urlID = NextURLID;
            stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO urls VALUES ('"+urlID+"','"+link.absUrl("href")+"','','')");
            NextURLID++;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException | SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to pass `url` as a parameter to your crawl method and research recursive algorithms (make sure to include the bit about termination, you can easily exhaust stack memory doing this).

Comment: Recursive crawling is essentially the same as a denial of service attack. So don't do it. Store the links in a db and go back and crawl them spaced out over time instead of boom boom boom recursive.